# Is this a typo?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The following is an extract from the Artin's monograph on the gamma function.[image]

Isn't the second inequality wrong. If not, how does the second inequality follow from the first.

Comment: Yes, that looks to be a typo.  It should be multiplication instead of addition within the $n$'th root.  Remember that $\log(a\times b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$

Comment: This appears to be attempting to get you to the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: Well it's more than a typo! How did such an error creep in?

Comment: @JohnMitchell: Probably just copy/paste. It doesn't look like anything more than a typo to me.

Comment: @JohnMitchell  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality seems to be correct indeed

$$-A\le-B\implies A\ge B$$

the typo seems to be in the sums of the $x_i$ terms on the RHS.

Comment: YES.  The value under the $n$th-root symbol should be the product $x_1....x_n,$ not the sum $x_1+...x_n.$.....One  difficulty in catching your own typos is that you know what should appear, so when reading your own work you might automatically adjust for an error, in the way that you might when   trying to understand someone else's work.